# Alfresco webscript: model script not used

Tags: alfresco

So I have a webscript with the following files:

- xyz.post.desc.xml
- xyz.post.json.ftl
- xyz.post.json.js

the desc is like:

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>xxx</shortname>
  <description>xxx</description>
  <url>/my/url/xyz?uri={id}</url>
  <format default="json">argument</format>
  <lifecycle>draft_public_api</lifecycle>
  <authentication>user</authentication>
  <transaction>none</transaction>
  <family>my/family</family>
</webscript>
```

in my js I do:

```
model.foo = "bar"
```

then in my ftl

```
${foo}
```

I have a ftl exception which says foo is undefined and I'm pretty sure now that I don't execute the js file itself.

What are the reasons that could explain the webscript is not running the model before evaluating the template?

note: from the url/alfresco/service/ webscript list, if I go in the details of xyz.post I can see the associated .js content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the records it's just me forgetting to pass : `requestContentType: Alfresco.util.Ajax.JSON` to the Ajax POST method

Answer (score 0):

The json.js is not your model, your model should be xyz.post.js

So it's obivous that foo is not defined.

Take a look at the [Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts#How_Do_I_Create_a_Web_Script.3F) for more information

Comment: you should have a look at all the repo webscript of the Share framework, there are xyz.post.json.js and work fine. I have other webscript following the same pattern as well.

Comment: From your question it wasn't clear that you were using Share webscripts :)

Comment: They are repository webscripts that are used to expose Alfresco repo data to the Share webapp, it's not a Share webscript to be exact. sorry for the confusion of my previous reply.